# How to insert special script into header?

Tags: javascript

I know how to insert a standard script to the body or header (changing .body or .header) depending on the case with:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src = 'https://url.com';
```

But I have a script that I need to insert into the header but it contains a var and I’m not sure how I should insert it.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var _iub = _iub || []; _iub.csConfiguration = {"countryDetection":true,"reloadOnConsent":true,"consentOnContinuedBrowsing":false,"perPurposeConsent":true,"purposes":"1,2,3,4,5","lang":"en","siteId":xxxx,"cookiePolicyId":494xxxx,"cookiePolicyUrl":"https://www.iubenda.com/privacy-policy/xxxx", "banner":{ "acceptButtonDisplay":true,"customizeButtonDisplay":true,"rejectButtonDisplay":true,"position":"float-bottom-center","backgroundOverlay":true }}; </script> <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.iubenda.com/cs/iubenda_cs.js" charset="UTF-8" async></script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: To clarify: You have `<script type="text/javascript"> var _iub = _iub || [];  ...` as a *string* in JavaScript and want to insert it programmatically into the page with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a script element and add the content with .innerHTML, afer just insert to body (or header).

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.innerHTML = ` var _iub = _iub || []; _iub.csConfiguration = {"countryDetection":true,"reloadOnConsent":true,"consentOnContinuedBrowsing":false,"perPurposeConsent":true,"purposes":"1,2,3,4,5","lang":"en","siteId":xxxx,"cookiePolicyId":494xxxx,"cookiePolicyUrl":"https://www.iubenda.com/privacy-policy/xxxx", "banner":{ "acceptButtonDisplay":true,"customizeButtonDisplay":true,"rejectButtonDisplay":true,"position":"float-bottom-center","backgroundOverlay":true }}; `;

document.body.appendChild(script);
```